# I can not understand the generateSequence function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm baffled by the `generateSequence` in Kotlin. I seem to be reading the manual all wrong:

This is the function signature (for `generateSequence` with seed):

```
fun <T : Any> generateSequence(
    seed: T?, 
    nextFunction: (T) -> T?
): Sequence<T>
```

So the `Sequence` should be of the same type of the seed and so should the next value going to the next iteration generation....

But the example in the man is:

```
fun fibonacci(): Sequence<Int> {
    return generateSequence(Pair(0, 1), { Pair(it.second, it.first + it.second) }).map { it.first }
}
​
println(fibonacci().take(10).toList()) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

So it would seem that the type of the `Sequence` is `Int` the seed is `Pair<Int, Int>`.

The generator function maps `Pair<Int, Int>` TO `Int`.
How is the next value sent to the generator constructed where is the next `Pair<Int, Int>` constructed (the output of the generator is `Int`...)?

And how on earth does the function know when to stop? The generator never returns `null`

Answer (score 8):

> So it would seem that the type of the Sequence is Int the seed is Pair.

The given `fibonacci()` function uses `generateSequence()` to generate a sequence of `Pair`, and then uses the `map` function to convert that sequence to a sequence of `Int`.

```
val pairs = generateSequence(Pair(0, 1), { Pair(it.second, it.first + it.second) })
// (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,5), (5,8) ...

val ints = pairs.map { it.first }
// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5
```

If it helps you think about it, you can imagine that the "entire" first sequence is generated before any pairs are converted to ints.

> And how on earth does the function know when to stop?

It doesn't. But the example uses [the `take()` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take.html) to truncate the sequence to the first 10 items, and then prints that instead of printing an infinite sequence.

The sequence is *`lazy`*; it only generates values (by calling the given generator function) when needed. So when `generateSequence()` returns, it hasn't generated anything yet -- just created a sequence that can do so. Similarly, when applied to a sequence, the `map()` call doesn't immediately map any values, just returns an amended sequence that will do so if/when any values get generated. It's only when `take()` is called that the sequence will generate (and map) some values; and because the take() stops after 10 items, it won't get around to generating any more than that.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss read it, it does make pairs.

But for the stopping problem I don't understand the answer.
As I understand it the take() function should be called only AFTER the fibonacci() function returns.... How does the program avoid an infinite loop?


Thanks

Comment: For that matter also the mapping to first in the Fibonacci function should be called after the generateSequence returns. So my question stands. What makes the generateSequence stop?  Thanks

Comment: The sequence is _lazy_; it only generates values (by calling the given generator function) when needed.  So when `generateSequence()` returns, it hasn't generated anything yet -- just created a sequence that _can_ do so.  Similarly, when applied to a sequence, the `map()` call doesn't immediately map any values, just returns an amended sequence that _will_ do so if/when any values get generated.  It's only when `take()` is called that the sequence will generate (and map) some values; and because the `take()` stops after 10 items, it won't get around to generating any more than that.

Comment: Wow, thanks that is a real eye opener. This is totality different to what is written in the man.